# MS Teams SDK Chatbot Textbox's height is too big

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Would anyone know why the text box of my MS Teams bot created using the Teams bot SDK has a text input bot that defaults to two lines instead of one? I presumed this setting would be in the manifest, but I really couldn't find the setting after many attempts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema).

[image]

Comment: We tried with this sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-all-cards/csharp), but it works fine at our end. Are you observing this issue in New Teams or Classic Teams?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT both classic and new teams. The text box will initially show as "two lines", but reduce to "one line" after I click on it.

Comment: Is it happening for all users? Maybe there's an Enter (newline) character sitting in there by accident (e.g. bumped the keyboard)?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow i couldn't find any stray "\n" anywhere in the app manifest.

Comment: No I meant in your Teams client - try backspace/delete to be sure